# Geocoding a React state property using Google Maps Geocoding API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to geocode one of the state props of my component using Google Maps Geocoding API. The value of the location is a string with the name of the city (ex. 'Stockholm'), and by using the geocoding API, I'm trying to transform it to geographic coordinates and update my Google Map.

However, I can't seem to work through this problem and I'am stuck at the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` error.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import BaseMap from './components/basemap.js';
import Card from './components/card.js';
import SearchBox from './components/search-box.js';

import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

import './index.css';

const google = window.google;
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar: '',
      username: 'bluejeans01',
      realName: '',
      location: '',
      followers: '',
      following: '',
      repos: '',
      address: geocoder.geocode({'address': this.state.location}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            this.setState({
              address: results.geometry.location
            })
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successfull because ' + status)
          }
        })
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}/>
        <Card data={this.state} />
        <BaseMap address={this.state.address}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  fetchApi(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          avatar: data.avatar_url,
          username: data.login,
          realName: data.name,
          location: data.location,
          followers: data.followers,
          following: data.following,
          repos: data.public_repos,
        })
      });
  }

  fetchUser(username) {
    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;

    this.fetchApi(url);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.username}`;

    this.fetchApi(url);
  }

}

export default App;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit--- scratch that...

You need to wait until you have set a value for this.state.location before you can initialize this.state.address

Basically change the fetchrequest to:

```
fetchApi(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          avatar: data.avatar_url,
          username: data.login,
          realName: data.name,
          location: data.location,
          followers: data.followers,
          following: data.following,
          repos: data.public_repos,
          address: [your function from the constructor])
        }
      });
  }
```

And use the data.location instead of the this.state.location, and set the value of address to "" in the constructor.

Comment: Could you please edit the part of the code so I could understand what are you suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer